# how to use svelte-package?

Tags: javascript, package, svelte

I have a codebase with for example 3 components.

I want to create one file with all svelte files and then export all of them.

so with that, I turned my codebase to become a library, which I can reuse with other codebases.

---

in javascript I always used `export default {func1, func2}`

so I can do in another files `import func1 from library`

---

and In the docs they suggest to use `@svelte.js/package`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sveltejs/package

which haven't done 0 docs about it, and nothing works.

[image]

except for this https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging but don't show the steps to do either.

---

for more info: I am not using sveltekit, but svelte.js framework.

---

I writed:

1. `npm i @svelte.js/package`
2. I writed then `svelte-package -w`

but there is error:  `command not found`

---

I also when installed the package get this

**33 VULNERABILITIES**

[image]

[image]

### is this a beta? should not use it?

if yes how to do then this?

---

another thing I am using vite as bundle if you interested in.

Comment: https://youtu.be/_TymiadmPrc see this youtube video, the command isn't `svelte-package -w` but `svelte-kit package`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is stated in the read-me:

> This is part of the SvelteKit framework and CLI.

This is meant for packaging output of SvelteKit; if you are not using that, then your output probably will not be compatible/correctly configured.